# Excel - How to sort column of email addresses by domain name?

Tags: excel, email, sorting

MS Excel

I have a column of email addresses.

I need to sort the column of emails a-z based on everything after the @. (on domain)

I have tried data / text to columns / delimiter @ but, I can only get the domain list that is split off to sort.

I also tried dragging this down in a new column:

```
=MID(A1, FIND("@",A1, 1)+1, 255)
```

The problem is, I just get a list of domains I can sort independent of the actual addresses.

I know I must be doing something wrong obviously.

What I have:

```
joeblo@somedomain.com
bluewidget@hypothetical.net
jonsmith@wonedomain.com
quickfox@adoman.com
lazydog@zdomain.fl.edu
```

What I want: (results can be in another column, or not, I don't care.)

```
quickfox@adoman.com
bluewidget@hypothetical.net
joeblo@somedomain.com
jonsmith@wonedomain.com
lazydog@zdomain.fl.edu
```

How do I get the darn sorted results with the entire email address into another column OR just sort in the same column based on everything after the @?????  (Preserving the whole email address, now sorted)

Thanks in advance for the learning experience.

Comment: Cant you put your MID formula in B:B, select all of A:B and sort by B? that maintains the link between A & B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy your email address in column A and domain in column B (using =MID(A1, FIND("@",A1, 1)+1, 255)) , then select both column A and B then sort by B Ascending.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way. @James: if you want a VBA solution, please ask, this would be funny to code (but I want to be sure you really need it)

Comment: @Jilji Thank you!! A small but critical detail every other solution I found left out was the selecting both columns and sort on b!! NICE...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2013 the new "flash fill" feature can do this also. Create a new column; start entering domains; after a bit you will see the rest of the domains magically appear below (at least they did for me).

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the content of your `A` email addresses in a blank `B` column
- Select the `B` column and type `Ctrl + h` (search and replace)
- In the *Search* field, type `*@` to capture everything before the @ plus the @
- Leave the *Replace* field blank and hit the *Replace all* button
- Sort the `B` column, you're done.

[image: search replace in excel before sorting]